# Finding variance and standard deviation of a random variable in an equation

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, standard-deviation

Suppose that X is a random variable with mean 17 and standard deviation 5. Also suppose that Y is a random variable with mean 45 and standard deviation 11. Find the variance and standard deviation of the random variable for the following case:

Z= 4 + 9X

I just need to know the process of finding it. Thanks!

Comment: There is no $Y$ in your equation.

Comment: There are other equations in the list that include a Y. I suppose I should just ask, "Suppose that X is a random variable with mean 17 and standard deviation 5. Find the variance and standard deviation of the random variable for Z= 4 + 9X"

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are constants, then for a random variable $X$, $$Var(a+bX)=b^2Var(X)$$
So here $$Var(Z)=Var(4+9X)=9^2Var(X)$$
And you already know $Var(X)$ from your given information, since the standard deviation is the square root of variance.

Comment: One more question: what happens to the 4? Thanks!

Comment: This is a property of the variance. The constant disappears. 
If a and b are constants, then:
$E(a + bX) = E(a) + E(bX) = a + bE(X)$... it doesn't disappear when you take the expectation.

For the variance,
$Var(a + bX) = b^2Var(X)$

You can actually prove this property:

$Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$, now use this same idea to show
$Var(a + bX) = b^2Var(X)$ by using:
$E((a+bX)^2)-[E(a+bX)]^2$